# magento show content according to condition in admin grid

Tags: magento

I have developed custom admin module.  I have used the usual methods _`prepareCollection` and _`prepareColumns` to show the data in Grid.

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
  {
        $collection = Mage::getModel("wallets/sellerrequest")->getCollection();
        $collection->getSelect()
        ->join( array('ce1' => 'customer_entity_varchar'), 'ce1.entity_id=main_table.seller_id and ce1.attribute_id = "5"', array('seller_name' => 'value'));

        $this->setCollection($collection);
        parent::_prepareCollection();
        return $this;
  }

  protected function _prepareColumns()
  {
        $helper = Mage::helper('sellers');

        $currency = (string) Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Directory_Model_Currency::XML_PATH_CURRENCY_BASE);

        $this->addColumn('id', array(
            'header' => $helper->__('Request No'),
            'index'  => 'id'
        ));


        $this->addColumn('Requested Amount', array(
            'header' => $helper->__('Requested Amount'),
            'index' => 'request_amount'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('Seller Name', array(
            'header'       => $helper->__('Seller Name'),
            'index'        => 'seller_name',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('Status', array(
            'header'        => $helper->__('Status'),
            'index'         => 'status_flag'            
        ));
```

All the data shows correctly according to the table values. But I want to show the Request Amount column values preceding with `$` sign, e.g. $300 etc. Also, I want to show the status flag according to condition. Means if the status flag is 1 then I want to show the value as "Approved", if flag is 2 then "Pending" etc. How should I customize the collection data and show in grid according to my requirement? Help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have answered to a question similar to your requirement

[How to properly add a shipping_description column in magento order grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26920895/how-to-properly-add-a-shipping-description-column-in-magento-order-grid/26924377#26924377)

Check my answer and try to compare with your problem. In this example there is the solution for our currency problem too.

So check this out.Hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Here you should implement Grid Renderer.

Here is complete tutorial for that : http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-custom-renderer-for-a-custom-column-in-magento-grid/

You can customize the value of any colum